# Pass Text From a Javascript Call To A Text Field In Form On Page Load?

Tags: javascript, forms

I thought I could find a solution for this online but I just can't seem to find a solution.

I have a form with a text field with id="filledonload" and it needs to grab a text value from a JavaScript function when the page loads?  How is this done?  I guess the better word would be auto "populate"

Thanks for the help..

Below is my super simple form.

```
<form id="form1" name="formname" method="post" action="">
<label>This Field Would Grab Text From JavaScript Function When The Page Loads
    <input type="text" name="filledonload" id="filledonload" />
</label>
```

Is get required to do this?  I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add one `onload` function to the `body` tag and do it there.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function doLoad(){
       //get the the input element and set the value
       var inp = document.getElementById('filledonload');
       inp.value = yourJsFunc();
    }

    function yourJsFunc(){
       //return whaterever you want here
       return 'value on load';
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="doLoad()">
    <form id="form1" name="formname" method="post" action="">
    <label>This Field Would Grab Text From JavaScript Function When The Page Loads
        <input type="text" name="filledonload" id="filledonload" />
    </label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can not get this to work. It makes me thing there's something wrong on my end.  I been trying scripts all night with no joy.

Comment: Thanks fmodos, I tried it on jsFiddle with no joy.  Any idea what I did wrong? Check it out.  http://jsfiddle.net/alwaysfinding/gYgcQ/

Comment: Sorry, i typed the wrong name for the yourjsfunc and script close tag... i am the phone and cant test it right now, but it would work

Comment: Darn! Still can't get it to function.

Comment: it's something with jsfiddle, I just tested your code in a html page and it worked... one thing you are missing in your code is the () after the function name, here is the update jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gYgcQ/1/, also my coding is working if you paste it to a html page it will work.

Comment: cool... if you can please vote me up and marking my answer as the best, thanks